# Shared config file for all mobilefirst server adapters

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Can i get config for all adapters at one place ? For example, i need store connection strings, httpserver addresses that needed across my mobilefirst server.
Mobilefirst version 8.0.
Thank you for advance!

Comment: You probably want to also mention basic stuff, like your mobilefirst version...

Answer (score 2):

In MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 you have the following options:

If using JavaScript adapters:

- Edit the connectivity settings from the MobileFirst Console,
- Or create a config file and use Maven commands (or the MobileFirst CLI in an upcoming CLI update), or other tools, to push the file to each adapter that requires that same set of connection settings.

Using this method there is no downtime to the server.

See the "Pull and Push Configurations" topic here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/javascript-adapters/

> Customized adapter properties can be shared using the adapter configuration file found in the Configuration files tab.
>   To do so, use the pull and push commands described below. For the properties to be shared, you need to change the default values given to the properties.
>
> Replace the DmfpfConfigFile placeholder with the actual value, for example: config.json. Then, run the command from the root folder of the adapter Maven project:
>
> - To pull the configurations file - `mvn adapter:configpull -DmfpfConfigFile=<path to a file that will store the configuration>`.
> - To push the configurations file - `mvn adapter:configpush -DmfpfConfigFile=<path to the file that stores the configuration>`.

If using Java adapters,

You can add JNDI properties to the server.xml of your application server, and using the [configurationAPI](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjava-mfp-server/html/com/ibm/mfp/adapter/api/ConfigurationAPI.html) (getServerJNDIProperty) you can read those properties in each of your adapters. However note that by using server.xml this will incur a downtime whenever you will want to update your list of connection properties.

Comment: thank you. i have seen this help info. im sorry,it`s very frogly for me. does it need to run the command from the root folder of the any adapter Maven project? i supose,will have differend addapters, different maven projects in my mobilefirst server. and how i could use this config file in all my addapters ?

Comment: You have to use it for each adapter. In v8.0 there is no "central location" for all adapters. Are you using JavaScript or Java adapters?

Comment: java adapters only

Comment: Okay, you should have mentioned in this in your question... correctly asked questions get better answers... I have updated my answer accordingly.